# Find duplicate values Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects and when I insert a new one I want to know if is duplicate or not.

```
    this.duplicate = false;

    for(let item of this.items){
        if(item.id && this.item.name === item.name) {  // this.item.name is the value that I try to insert
//item.id (if is add, id = null, is update id = value)
            this.$notify({
                group: "notify",
                text: "Duplicate value! ",
                type: "error"
            });
            this.duplicate = true ;
        }
    }

    if(!this.duplicate){
        // post/put request
    }
```

This works just for add (post request), on update I get always duplicate value.

Answer (score 1):

You can check before you add

```
  const newItem; // comes from request

  const duplicateIndex = this.items
    .map(item => item.name)
    .indexOf(newItem.name);
  // returns index of Object that has same name as newItem's name 
  // or -1 if not found

  // Post request
  if (newItem.id == null) {
    if (duplicateIndex) {
      this.$notify({
        group: "notify",
        text: "Duplicate value! ",
        type: "error"
      });
    } else {
      this.items.push(newItem);
    }
  // Put request
  } else {
    this.items[duplicateIndex] = newItem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, Idea is to get the existing Id of record, and match with other records, if other record's id and this id mis-match then you can say this is proper duplicate value

```js
this.duplicate = false;

for(let item of this.items){ 

var existingId=this.item.id || -1; // null coalescing operator (??) is using a logical OR (||):


        
        if (existingId!=item.id && this.item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(item.name.toUpperCase()) == -1) {
           this.$notify({
                group: "notify",
                text: "Duplicate value! ",
                type: "error"
            });
            this.duplicate = true ;
        } else {
             //nothing found
        }        
    }

    if(!this.duplicate){
        // post/put request
    }
```